# How to use comments or something else to split up code into sections

Tags: objective-c, comments, naming, code-documentation

In my intro to programming courses, most things were split up into sections with comments, like this:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
{
    @protected
    NSMutableArray *_objects
}

/* constructors */
+(id) initWithObjects: (NSMutableArray *) objects;
-(id) initWithObjects: (NSMutableArray *) objects;

/* properties */
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objects;

/* methods */
- (void) haveFunWithObjects;
```

I find this to be a useful way of organizing things, but often times, I'll need to preface or insert documentation in the middle of a rather esoteric section of code with a brief description, and then I get confused as to how I should be documenting it:

```
@interface NDTuple : NSObject
{
    @protected
    NSMutableArray *_components;
    NSUInteger _dim;
}

/* constructors */

/* This constructor initializes the components array to elements all of 0 */
+(id) initToZeroForDim: (NSUInteger) dim;
-(id) initToZeroForDim: (NSUInteger) dim;

+(id) initWithComponents: (NSMutableArray *)components;
-(id) initWithComponents: (NSMutableArray *)components;

/* properties */
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *components;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger dim;

/* methods */
- (NDTuple *) minus: (NDTuple *) subTuple;

- (void) replaceComponentAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index withComponent:(id)anObject;

- (id) componentAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index;
```

Maybe this wasn't the best example, but **what I'm really asking is if there is a better way to split up code into its common sections?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#pragma mark` to separate sections. Xcode will show these values when you drop down the list of symbols in the file.

Example:

```
#pragma mark Constructors
```

You even do:

```
#pragma mark -
```

to show a line in the symbol drop down list.

Comment: Lol I don't know why I forgot to accept this answer